# Request fails with HTTP 400 - Bad Request in Chrome browser

Tags: asp.net, ajax, google-chrome, outsystems

I have a web application on ASP that was built with Outsystems platform. On the page I have form and several AJAX requests. For some reasons on some computer (same application, same version of Chrome) AJAX request fails with 400 - bad request (Doesn't happen in IE or Firefox). I looked inside the request and on the verb part of the one who has error I have information from the viewstate of the previous AJAX request. (Also on the computer that have problems I tried to clean cookies, reinstall Chrome but it didn't helped.)

Please does anyone have an ideas with what it can be connected to?

Right request:
[image]

Bad request:
[image]

Comment: could you please provide both of those as text? and please also the code part where the post url is set?

Comment: What version of the OutSystems platform are you using?
Are the misbehaving Chromes consistently misbehaving? If you try to use them in incognito mode will they still misbehave?

Comment: I use 9.0, consistently, in incognito the same

Comment: Can you check if the Chrome Developer Tools network pane shows information coherent with what Fiddler is showing? Is your application including any version of jQuery or some jQuery plugins?

Comment: Did you check the log error in the service center? Its will help :)

Comment: Did you perhaps find a solution on your own?

Comment: My guess would be that the request is too long, IIS Express has a 64KB limit.  That's checkable in Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with .net core and chrome with open DEVTOOLS.
I used [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4) to investigate, and the issue was because of some missing *.css.map files.

Comment: I've had the exact same issue and was using FF as a workaround. You can either add the .map files, or turn off _Enable CSS source maps_ / _Enable Javascript source maps_.

Comment: Let's note: In order to turn off css/js source maps, you need in DEVTOOLS settings (F1) uncheck checkboxes @Mathemats noted.

Comment: FYI clicking the link starts an `.exe` download